# Splitting WebRTC audio streams and outputting them in different channels of my output audio device

Tags: audio, webrtc

I have a simple WebRTC (audio) group chat application, heavily based on the code in [this repo](https://github.com/anoek/webrtc-group-chat-example), between a bunch of laptops on a LAN in different rooms. On each of the laptops connected to the chat, the code automatically mixes all the other audio streams (all minus the captured stream of that laptop, i.e. the normal mode of operation of an audio chat).

On one of the laptops connected to the chat (let's call it `laptop0`), I'd like to be able to output the different received streams (3 in my case, as there are 4 total connected laptops) on as many different channels of the output device selected through WebRTC, i.e. the audio from

1. `laptop1` to output channel 1
2. `laptop2` to output channel 2
3. `laptop3` to output channel 3

The idea is that I'll connect the output to feed it to a DAW to add some effects to the different channels.

Assuming that I do have an output audio device with enough channels, is there an easy way to do that?
A snippet of the code I assume being in the region where this could be implemented (according to my extremely poor understanding of WebRTC ) is the following.

```
var peer_connection = new RTCPeerConnection(
    {"iceServers": ICE_SERVERS},
    {"optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]} 
);
peers[peer_id] = peer_connection;

peer_connection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
        signaling_socket.emit('relayICECandidate', {
            'peer_id': peer_id, 
            'ice_candidate': {
                'sdpMLineIndex': event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                'candidate': event.candidate.candidate
            }
        });
    }
}
peer_connection.onaddstream = function(event) {
    console.log("onAddStream", event);
    var remote_media = USE_VIDEO ? $("<video>") : $("<audio>");
    remote_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
    // remote_media.attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
    if (MUTE_AUDIO_BY_DEFAULT) {
    remote_media.attr("muted", "true");
    }
    remote_media.attr("controls", "");
    peer_media_elements[peer_id] = remote_media;
    $('body').append(remote_media);
    attachMediaStream(remote_media[0], event.stream);
}


/* Add our local stream */
peer_connection.addStream(local_media_stream);
```